# Photodiodes over Phototransistors

Tags: solar-cell, semiconductors, photodiode, phototransistor

Current solar panels being manufactured are not considered efficient. I have also read articles saying there is talk or even ongoing  research about four P-N layers (i.e: PNPN or vice versa) for solar panels. What I mean is, if more junctions equate to more absorption, why are photo-transistors  not used in solar panels instead of photo-diodes?

Answer (score 3):

The point of phototransistors is not to make more current from the same light, but to amplify that current.  That's fine when the light is a signal.

Amplification makes no sense when the point is to get power from the light.  The power to run the amplifier would reduce the overall power ultimately received from the light-to-electrical-power converter.

> If the diode activates through light, why do majority of the circuits utilize a power source?

There are two ways to use a photodiode in a circuit to sense light:

As a photocell.  In this case the power converted from the light is used directly.  The diode becomes a voltage/current source.  This signal is then amplified to perform the desired function.

As a leaky diode.  In this case, the circuit keeps the diode reverse-biased, usually at a fixed voltage.  The amount the diode "leaks" is proportional to the incident light.

This method is the more common because it results in a faster response and is more linear with the light intensity.  One reason the response can be faster is because the voltage doesn't change.  Parasitic capacitance therefore ideally doesn't matter.

Comment: Thank you. I understand perfectly. But that begs another question. All the photo-diode circuits I've seem make use of a separate power supply for powering the diode. If the diode activates through light, why do majority of the circuits utilize a power source? What's the sense in that? And if they do need a separate source, do solar panels also have such a source?

Comment: The reply to your comment is already in this answer. When the diode is powered, its used with reverse bias. Re-read Olins answer, and make note of point no. 2 and outwards.

Comment: If I wanted to simulate a photocell on a simulator, how can I do that? Because I tried it on Proteus and apparently it doesn't work without a power source.  Or at least it didn't work the way I tried it.